# ¿Como agregar diferentes opciones en varias lineas de un TextBox seleccionando desde ListBox VB6?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

Soy nuevo en el Visual Basic 6 y tengo una duda, he estado tratando de realizar desde hace un tiempo un ListBox que me "imprima" la selección de la lista en un TextBox y no encontraba la solución hasta que hoy toqueteando  dí con una posible. Creé un botón de comandos con los siguientes parámetros:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    If List1.Selected(i) Then
    Text5.Text = List1.List(i)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Teniendo un ListBox identificado como `List1` y el cuadro de texto en el que deseo "imprimir" denominado `Text5` La cuestión es que necesito seleccionar múltiples opciones y que estas (Nuevamente) se "Impriman" en una linea aparte según yo vaya seleccionando y agregando con el botón diferentes ítems en la lista. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Como extra en las propiedades del `Text5` está configurado para aceptar multilineas y el `List1` para soportar la selección múltiple.

En resumen, deseo realizar una selección múltiple en un cuadro de texto independiente de la lista. El porque es simple, estoy trabajando con una base de datos de Access para poder almacenar la información, pero necesito agregar información múltiple en un solo Field y no se me permite por lo menos con VB6.

Alguna sugerencia para complementar el código u otro método es aceptable, GRACIAS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mira, la verdad pasando por aquí y vi tu pregunta, y claro esta que en vb.net esta bien, pero si en realidad querías hacerlo en vb6 o anteriores, solo tenias que poner

```
Private Sub c1_Click()

For u = 0 To 5

l1.AddItem (u)

      Next u

For i = 0 To l1.ListCount - 1


    t2 = t2 + l1.List(i) + Chr(13)

    Next i
End Sub
```

Te explico, c1 es un botón de comando, podía ser el mismo tuyo, pero me gustan los nombres cortos, l1 es un cuadro de lista, y t2 es un cuadro de texto ("Recuerda que debes poner la opción de multiline del cuadro de texto en true"), y chr(13) es el código para retorno de carro, o mejor dicho enter. en pocas palabras, lo único que debías hacer era poner la opción de multiline del cuadro de texto en true en caso de que no la tuvieras ya que si no es así no te dejara agregar saltos de linea ya que sera de manera lineal cualquier cosa que agregáramos al cuadro de texto, y agregar chr(13) para ir agregando un espacio de carro en cada ingreso de los items del cuadro de lista, en este ejemplo agrego al cuadro de lista los números del 0 al 5, y luego los agrego al cuadro de texto. espero te ayude mi explicación.
daría un resultado así

```
0

1

2

3

4

5
```

si no le pones multiline en true quedaría igual a como lo estabas haciendo así agregaras esta corrección

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Aclaro, este seria el resultado de t2 a mostrar

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Dєηyη,

Puedes usar la propiedad [`SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) del `ListView` para obtener solo las filas seleccionadas de la siguiente forma:

```
For Each row As String In List1.SelectedItems
    'Imprimo todas las selecciones con salto de línea en el textBox'
    Text5.Text += row & Environment.NewLine
Next
```

Comment: Me sale error de sintaxis y no se en donde exactamente l

Comment: Pon el codigo completo para ver, a mi me ha funcionado en mis pruebas

Comment: Funcionó en .NET Muchas gracias!